# How many threads does the user code of a Flutter application use?

Tags: multithreading, flutter, dart

Documentation states that [isolate has a single thread of execution and shares no mutable objects with other isolates](https://dart.dev/guides/language/concurrency).

At the same time all parts of user code of a Flutter application have access to mutable global variables.

Does this mean that user code in Flutter application is always running in one thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Dart is a single-thread language. Isolate run in a single thread.  Each isolate has its own memory, space, and everything. Flutter runs all its code in a single isolate but you can create multiple isolates as your need.